# Suggestion on algorithm selection and implementation

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Good day,

I'm working on the next problem and have minimum knowledge about machine learning (ML):

1. Given the list of articles (A's, text format) and search string (SQ), select and order most relative articles (A's) to the search string (SQ).
2. Optimize point #1 on case if new article (A) is added - i.e. so search will account new record and it will be taken into consideration next time.

I've selected spark as the engine for ML calculations and found examples, which counts IDF models (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf). This is smths that results in the end with feature-vector of frequencies of term in the article:

(8,[0,1,4],[0.287... (8,[0,1,6],[0.287... (8,[1,3,4],[0.0,0...

(sorry for truncated results)

At this point I stuck. It looks like we might need to calculate similar vector for SQ and order somehow articles by closest. Not sure how to do that though.

What would be right way forward? Can you please share/point to examples with implementation?

Thank you in advance,

Vitaliy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the short roadmap which worked for me (verified on really small data set):

1. Build TF-IDF for corpus, obtain "features" vectors
2. Build IDF for search term, obtain "features" vector
3. Train kmeans on corpus features (from step 1), get "article id" to cluster mapping.
4. Predict search term cluster (from step 2 and 3), get "search term" cluster.
5. Filter articles by needed cluster (from step 4).
6. Filter further articles in selected cluster with LSH, order further by distance between features in cluster and search term.